# Changing properties in the custom control from another Class

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, controls

I created custom control with properties that change its shape. It **works perfectly** if I change propertie "circle" to true/false, or propertie "triangle" the same way.

To set that properties I use a code as follows:

```
public bool circle { get; set; }
public bool triangle { get; set; }

 protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
 .
 . //Drawing figures
 .
```

However, I stucked at thinking how to organize shape changing remotely, e.g., from another Class.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How can it work **perfectly**, if both are set to true? Do you get a Triangular circle?
A better approach would be to have an enumeration of shape types that you could set. This would also facilitate other things like octagons or stars and gives a mutually exclusive set of options.

Comment: if both are "true" it draws both figures. It's sortable! The point of question is "how to control remotely from another Class".